# Add text on the page in ReactJS when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display the text from the `addInfo` function to my page with JSX! Please share advice. Don't just give me the answer; explain the steps to solve it. Thank you in advance.

```js
let view = ''

const addInfo = () => {

  view = 'Hi my name is'

  showDetails()

}

const showDetails = () => {

  const view = ( 
  <div>
    <h1> Move on </h1>
    <button onClick = { addInfo }> show details </button>
    <p> {view} </p>
  </div>
  )

  ReactDOM.render(view, document.getElementById('root'))

}

showDetails()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<span id="root"></span>
```

Comment: So, you have the addInfo function, which calls the showDetails function, which calls the addInfo function on click? Sound confusing to you?

Comment: You have a syntax error. You're going to get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'view' before initialization` when you try to run this code.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you use the name `view` for both the text you want to display and the element to be rendered. To fix this, simply change the name of one of these.

```js
let view = ''

const addInfo = () => {

  view = 'Hi my name is'

  showDetails()

}

const showDetails = () => {

  const renderView = ( /* Changed this variable name */
  <div>
    <h1> Move on </h1>
    <button onClick = { addInfo }> show details </button>
    <p> {view} </p>
  </div>
  )

  ReactDOM.render(renderView, document.getElementById('root')) /* Changed here, too */

}

showDetails()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.